# Date manipulation with regex

Tags: php, regex

I need to change following format `20:35:20 Feb 24, 2012 PST` to `Feb 23, 2013`.
I needed it to be generic as it might be used for many years to come.

Comment: What's the corellation between these two dates? Are you sure you need regex to do this? =)

Comment: You need to convert it, add a year, and subtract a day?

Comment: You do not want to use regex for this. Use PHP's date/time manipulation functions.

Comment: Gift Certificates purchased date and GC expiry date. it's 1yr valid. Any solution appreciated. Thanks guys ;)

Comment: @Mat: thanks Mat. if you are familiar do you mind dropping me a quick line of code?

Comment: @Josh: sounds good Josh. would appreciate those few lines as I spent 2many hrs in front of screen 2day. thanks man ;)

Comment: Why don't you give it a shot first, and show your attempt? I'm sure someone will help you out if you can't get it just right?

Comment: @Mat: I am sick of it Mat.. Had to many of those 2day, it's almost 2am, I wanna go to sleep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regex isn't necessary here**. You can simply use [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

```
$input = "20:35:20 Feb 24, 2012";

// Convert to timestamp, add a year, subtract a day
echo date("M j, Y", strtotime($input . " + 1 Year - 1 Day"));

// Outputs: Feb 23, 2013
```

Answer (score 1):

`\d{2}:\d{2}\d{2}\s+([A-Z]+\s+\d{1,2}\s+\d{4})\s+[A-Z]+`

The date will be in the first group.  If you want the regex to match the entire string (rather than match a date in the middle of the string), put ^ at the start and $ at the end.  This regex is meant to be used with case-insensitive matching.

If any parts of your example date/time are optional, let me know, and I can modify this.

Comment: Was trying to delete this but I guess I'll let it sit.  I didn't realize the dates were different.

Answer (score 1):

See live example: http://codepad.org/xDCbKZxV

```
function isLeapYear($year)
{
  return ((($year % 4) == 0) && (($year % 100) != 0) || (($year % 400) == 0));
}

$date = strtotime('20:35:20 Feb 24, 2012 PST');

if ( isLeapYear(date('Y', $date)) )
  $date += (60*60*24*366);  // One year (leap year!)
else
  $date += (60*60*24*365); // One year
```